# Invalid username error when calling REST API with JWT token

Tags: wordpress, jwt

I've set up Wordpress locally and have the plugin JWT Authentication for WP REST API installed. There have been no problems generating a token in Postman.

[image: screenshot of token generation]

But when I try calling other API endpoints using the generated token, I get an invalid_username error.

[image: screenshot of error message]

I'm using Wordpress 6.3.

Edit:

After some more testing, I found that the error happened in wp_authenticate_username_password from wp-includes/user.php. The values it received for $username and $password were {"typ" and "JWT","alg"", respectively. Still don't know why that is, though.